# ERROR TypeError: Cannot create property 'id' on number '1' . Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I'm using angular 7 and I need to send a request from client-side to server-side. This is the structure of the client-side request that need to achieve.

```
{
    "title" : "Test Title",
    "user": {
        "id" : 7
    },
    "category": {
        "id" : 2
    },
    "description" : "test description",
    "quantity" : "2"
    
}
```

And this is the model class in angular.
sampleRequest.ts

```
export class SampleRequest {
  title: string;
  user: { id: number};
  category: { id: number};
  description: string;
  quantity: number;
}
```

Then I'm getting input data using angular Reactive forms. The user Id is getting through the JWT token, that id of the currently logged-in user. This is the template file. sample-request.component.html

```
<form novalidate [formGroup]="requestForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <p>
          <mat-form-field class="form-field-width">
            <input matInput placeholder="Title" type="text" formControlName="title" name="title" required>
            <mat-error *ngIf="requestForm.get('title').hasError('required')">Title is required</mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
        </p>
        <p>
          <mat-form-field class="form-field-width">
            <input matInput placeholder="Select Category" type="number" formControlName="category" name="category" required>
            <mat-error *ngIf="requestForm.get('category').hasError('required')">Category is required</mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
        </p>
        <p>
          <mat-form-field class="form-field-width">
            <input matInput placeholder="Description" type="test" formControlName="description" name="description"
              required>
            <mat-error *ngIf="requestForm.get('description').hasError('required')">Description is required</mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
        </p>
        <p>
          <mat-form-field class="form-field-width">
            <input matInput placeholder="Quantity" type="number" formControlName="quantity" name="quantity" required>
            <mat-error *ngIf="requestForm.get('quantity').hasError('required')">Quantity is required</mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="requestForm.get('quantity').hasError('pattern')">Please enter numbers only</mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
        </p>
        <button type="submit" [disabled]="requestForm.invalid" mat-raised-button color="primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
```

And this is sample-request.component.ts file.

```
export class SampleRequestComponent implements OnInit {

  requestForm: FormGroup;
  sampleRequest: SampleRequest;


  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private userService: UserService, private tokenStorage: TokenStorageService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.requestForm = this.fb.group({
      title : ['', Validators.required],
      category : [''],
      description: ['', Validators.required],
      quantity: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern]]
    });
   }


  onSubmit() {
    this.sampleRequest.title = this.requestForm.get('title').value;
    this.sampleRequest.category.id = this.requestForm.get('category').value;
    this.sampleRequest.user.id = this.tokenStorage.getUser().id;
    this.sampleRequest.description = this.requestForm.get('description').value;
    this.sampleRequest.quantity = this.requestForm.get('quantity').value;
    console.log(this.sampleRequest);
    this.userService.newSampleRequest(this.sampleRequest)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.isSuccessful = true;
          this.isProgress = true;
        },
        error => {
          this.isFailed = true;
          this.isProgress = true;
          this.errMsg = error.error.message;
        }
      );

  }

}
```

****And I also get an error that 'title' is undefined.****

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here the SampleRequest which you are exporting is undefined, as you mentioned

```
export class SampleRequest {
  title: string;
  user: { id: number};
  category: { id: number};
  description: string;
  quantity: number;
}
```

it is a class you need to initialize like

```
sampleRequest: SampleRequest = new SampleRequest();
```

by this way, you will get all your sample request property in your this.sampleRequest

Comment: property undefined is solved. but still ERROR TypeError: Cannot create property 'id' on number '1' is counted.

Comment: I am seeing there are 2 id's on which line you are getting the error?

Comment: both this.sampleRequest.category.id = this.requestForm.get('category').value; and 
    this.sampleRequest.user.id = this.tokenStorage.getUser().id;

Comment: make user: { id: string} and check

Answer (score 1):

I have observed 2 things in your code.

1. you've used reactive forms, in that case one can use formControlName only. As specifying it only is sufficient for angular to identify field name.
2. When we use number type in input field and we use *.value* to get a value it returns string. so when you try to assign string to number typescript may throw error or warning.

Changing these things may help you understand and fix the issue
Thanks.